# Detecting and categorizing device drivers in a running system

Tags: linux-kernel, devices

How can I obtain what device drivers are incorporated in a running kernel?

More than this, how can I categorize these device drivers?

For instance, this is a Linux kernel conceptual map, from Wikipedia:

[image]

How can I distribute detected device drivers into correspondent area in the map above?

My impression is that such info could be obtained from kernel config files.

*(I am not expecting answer to be in a graphical form. Textual categorization would suffice, but with the appropriate categories that can be, overall, matched to the areas in the picture.)*

Comment: Do you want the categorization purely out of interest, or is there some ultimate purpose to it?

Comment: Purely out of interest. :) @ilkkachu

Answer (score 2):

You can list the loaded drivers using **lsmod**. For example,

`[root@vm bin]# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
coretemp               13435  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            69884  0 
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
sg                     40721  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
pcspkr                 12718  0 
vmw_balloon            13415  0 
parport_pc             28165  0 
parport                42348  2 ppdev,parport_pc
vmw_vmci               67106  0 
i2c_piix4              22106  0 
shpchp                 37032  0 
ip_tables              27240  0 
xfs                   939662  3 
libcrc32c              12644  1 xfs
sr_mod                 22416  0 
cdrom                  42556  1 sr_mod
sd_mod                 45497  3 
crc_t10dif             12714  1 sd_mod
ata_generic            12910  0 
crct10dif_generic      12647  0 
pata_acpi              13038  0 
mptspi                 22542  2 
scsi_transport_spi     30732  1 mptspi
mptscsih               40150  1 mptspi
vmwgfx                176029  1 
drm_kms_helper        125008  1 vmwgfx
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  1 
crct10dif_common       12595  3 crct10dif_pclmul,crct10dif_generic,crc_t10dif
ttm                    93441  1 vmwgfx
crc32c_intel           22079  1 
ata_piix               35038  0 
drm                   349210  4 ttm,drm_kms_helper,vmwgfx
mptbase               105960  2 mptspi,mptscsih
serio_raw              13462  0 
libata                218730  3 pata_acpi,ata_generic,ata_piix
vmxnet3                53833  0 
i2c_core               40582  3 drm,i2c_piix4,drm_kms_helper
floppy                 69417  0 
dm_mirror              22135  0 
dm_region_hash         20862  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 18411  2 dm_region_hash,dm_mirror
dm_mod                113292  11 dm_log,dm_mirror`

Then to further understand what each driver relates to, use **modinfo**

`[root@vm bin]# modinfo coretemp
filename:       /lib/modules/3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64/kernel/drivers/hwmon/coretemp.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Intel Core temperature monitor
author:         Rudolf Marek <r.marek@assembler.cz>
rhelversion:    7.2
srcversion:     39EE385A7A807BDCB75C480
alias:          x86cpu:vendor:0000:family:*:model:*:feature:*00E7*
depends:

intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         CentOS Linux kernel signing key
sig_key:        79:AD:88:6A:11:3C:A0:22:35:26:33:6C:0F:82:5B:8A:94:29:6A:B3
sig_hashalgo:   sha256
parm:           tjmax:TjMax value in degrees Celsius (int)`

You then can use this info and categorize where each driver belongs to.

Comment: That is cool, but do you have any idea how to do categorization in an automatic, od semi-automatic way? I see we can extract dependency tree from "lsmod". Do you have any other idea?

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy way. Do you need to do it on multiple machines? To achieve what you ask, you would need to have a Map that holds this info [which drivers relates to which category]. Then you can build a script that find active drivers and look for a match.